# Is there a python syntax checker that can ignore ' assigned to but never used' when locals() is present?

Tags: python, vim, syntax, pyflakes

suppose I have the code

```
def foo():
    bar = 1
    wibble = 3
    return locals()
```

my current syntax checker (flake8 with syntastic.vim) will throw a 'assigned to but never used' error on both variables. However locals() implies something is they are in fact being used, if not explicitly.

```
def foo():
    bar = 1
    wibble = 3 # <-- I still want this to throw as it is definitely not being used
    return bar
```

Is there any python checker or custom setting that will be locals() aware and lenient?

EDIT:

This is a quick and dirty solution for vim/syntastic/flake8 that will suppress the warning in your .vimrc

```
"Ignore unused variable warnings whenever locals() is being used in a file                                                              
function! LocalsWarningSuppress()                                              
    if ( search("locals()",'nw') > 0)                                          
        let g:syntastic_python_checker='flake8 --ignore=W806'                  
    else                                                                       
        let g:syntastic_python_checker='flake8'                                
    endif                                                                      
endfunction 

au BufWritePre **/(filter_pattern)*py call LocalsWarningSuppress()
```

Comment: Returning `locals()` is not that great an idea, now is it.. :-)

Comment: Martijn: Yeah I agree it can be a bad pattern, but it can be good for brevity under some circumstances. Please assume I'm maintaining someone elses code :-)

Comment: Then simply replace that with `return {'bar': bar, 'wibble': wibble}` and be done with it. `pyflakes` happy, you happy as a maintainer!

Comment: If there's no real solution I'll write a filter in syntastic itself but it would be just a crude 'is locals() present in the next n lines' thing. I just want to suppress the warning for now and that is very doable.

Comment: If you are constantly returning `locals()`, it might be a sign that you need a class; as it would seem your methods are just acting as a namespace.  Converting the code into a class, and accessing the variables/properties through an instance would satisfy the linter and probably earn you a silent prayer of thanks from the next guy who has to maintain it.

Comment: Please tell me that the foo is not called like: `locals().update(foo())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Even [`pylint`](https://www.pylint.org/), the most powerful and nitpicky Python linter I'm aware of, isn't clever enough to detect this case.  But if it were, it would probably complain that you're using `locals()` in the first place.  :)

On the other hand, and unlike pyflakes, pylint does support [magic comments](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#messages-control-options) to ignore specific problems.  But I must warn you that pylint is extremely picky (and thus slow) out of the box, so you'll want to spend a few minutes upfront to cut its [list of checks](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-messages) down to just the things you actually care about.

There *is* a [ticket closed as wontfix](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/641) for improving this behavior in the specific case of string formatting. It appears that pylint developers don't want to implement this as a feature.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the ticket. I'll see how much it keeps bothering me :)